# Why is "*" CSS styling overriding "button" or "nav button" styling?

Tags: css, margin

Using Chrome's Developer Tools, I can see that the margin styling is being taken from the global setting. Which is weird because I have a more specific `nav button` style added too.

What could be causing the global margin styling to be selected over a more specific one?

```
*{
    margin: 0;
}

nav button {
    background-color: #4CAF50;
    color: white;
    padding: 14px 20px;
    margin: 8px, 8px;
    border: 8px, 8px; 
    cursor: pointer;
    width: 100%; 
}
```

Comment: Delete the comma. `margin: 8px 8px` is correct, `margin: 8px, 8px` is not. Did that help?

Comment: Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`margin: 8px, 8px;` it should be `margin: 8px 8px;` and `border: 8px, 8px;` it should `border: 8px 8px;`

```
nav button {
    background-color: #4CAF50;
    color: white;
    padding: 14px 20px;
    margin: 8px 8px;
    border: 8px 8px; 
    cursor: pointer;
    width: 100%; 
}
```

The margin property has four values, `margin: top_margin right_margin bottom_margin left_margin;` if you use `margin: 8px 8px;` it represents top margin value is `8px` and right value is `8px`.